# Diagonalizable matrix over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: matrices

How do I show that the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}2&a\\a&1\end{pmatrix}$$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$? And can we say the same if we replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Know any sufficient conditions for a matrix to be diagonalizable?  Why not apply one?

Comment: @ErickWong Diagonalizable if there exists a basis of eigenvectors, but I don't know how to apply this

Comment: @JimmyP What about a matrix with *distinct* eigenvalues?

Comment: @A.G. What about a matrix with distinct eigenvalues? Also I don't know how to get the eigenvalues, I thought about computing the characteristic polynomial, but then i get $t^2-3t+2-a^2$

Comment: @JimmyP Distinct eigenvalues $\Rightarrow$ [diagonalizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Characterization). Eigenvalues $\Leftrightarrow$ solutions to $t^2-3t+2-a^2=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of the matrix is $(2-X)(1-X)-a^2=X^2-3X+2-a^2$. The discriminant of this quadratic is $\Delta=1+4a^2\gt 0$ ($a$ is real) so we always have two distinct real eigenvalues. Therefore the matrix is diagonalisable.

If $a\in\mathbb{C}$ take the following matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 2&{i\over 2}\\{i\over 2}&1\end{bmatrix}$ this matrix is not diagonalisable. It has ${3\over 2}$ as a double eigenvalue and the only $n\times n$ matrix who has an $n^{th}$ order eigenvalue that is diagonalisable is $\lambda I_n$

Comment: I don't fully understand why your complex matrix isn't diagonalizable

Comment: It has $1$ as a double root of its characteristic polynomial so assume it is diagonalisable. One can write $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with $1$ on the diagonal. So $D=I_2$ and $A=PP^{-1}=I_2$. This is absurd because $2\neq 1$ and $i\neq 0$....

Comment: @marwalix Trace $=3$, so double eigenvalue $1$ is not possible. Did you mean $3/2$?

Comment: You're right. I will edit.

Comment: Please correct my previous comment to reflect that the double eigenvalue is ${3\over 2}$ the proof is the same

Answer (score 0):

**First try.**
In $\mathbb{R}$, every symmetric matrix ($A^T=A$) is diagonalizable.
This applies here.
In $\mathbb{C}$, every Hermitian matrix ($A^H=A$) is diagonalizable.
This does not ($a^* \neq a$ for e.g. $a=i$) apply here.

**Second try.**
For a matrix to be not diagonalizable, there have to be eigenvalues with algebraic multiplicity greater one.
Solve
$$0=det \left(\begin{pmatrix}2-\lambda&a\\a&1-\lambda\end{pmatrix}\right) = (2-\lambda)(1-\lambda)-a^2 = \lambda^2-3\lambda +(2-a^2).$$
$$\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{3\pm\sqrt{9-4\cdot(2-a^2)}}{2}$$
So
$$\lambda_1=\lambda_2 \iff 9=4(2-a^2) \iff \frac{9}{4}-2=-a^2\iff a=\pm i\frac{1}{2}$$
This again shows that this is only can be a problem for $\mathbb{C}$.
If we choose one of those two $a$, w.l.o.g. $a=i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}}$, we geht 
$$\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{3}{2}$$
Now we try to get the eigenvectors for this.
$$\text{Ker} \left| \begin{pmatrix}2-\lambda&a\\a&1-\lambda\end{pmatrix} \right| =\text{Ker} \left| \begin{pmatrix}2-\frac{3}{2}&i\frac{1}{{2}}\\i\frac{1}{{2}}&1-\frac{3}{2}\end{pmatrix} \right| $$
By looking at it, you can tell that the eigenspace can't have a dimension of two.
Therefore there is no basis of eigenvectors.
**Yes, this can be done faster, but the same case in three dimensions doesn't work that way.**